# Returning NULL Structure

Tags: opencv

I am calling a function which returns a structure of the type CvBox2D, however I want to check for an error in the function and return NULL if there is an error.

```
CvBox2D function()
{
    ...

    if(ERROR)
        return NULL;

    ...
}
```

I am getting an error : cannot convert from 'int' to 'CvBox2D'

Comment: Use exceptions or return codes instead. Or, as pointed out by Esenti, return a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your function return type is `CvBox2D`, so you can't convert a (NULL) pointer to it.

If you really need to return "nothing" if the check inside the function fails, you can change the return type to a *pointer* to `CvBox2D`:

```
CvBox2D* function()
{
    ...
}
```

You will also have to change the way the returned object is created inside your function.

Note that using raw pointers in C++ usually isn't a good idea.
Take a look at [std::shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) (available in C++11) if you think you really have to use pointers.

Comment: I want to return something so that I can check for the error .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return some error code, you can do the following:

```
int function(CvBox2D* output) {
  // code...

  // Assign to struct.
  output->center = ...;

  if (error) {
    return RC_ERROR_FOO;
  }

  return RC_OK;
}
```

Then you call this function using a struct you've already allocated (for example, on the stack):

```
{
  CvBox2D myBox;
  int retval = function(&myBox);
  if (RC_OK == retval) {
    printf("Good! Angle of box: %g", myBox.angle);
  } else {
    printf("Error: %d", retval);
  }
}
```

Where `RC_OK`, `RC_ERROR_FOO` are defined as constant integers, or better, as an enum (if you're using C++).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers solve your problem, but if you want to keep the signature of your function, instead of returning an error code, you should throw an exception.